# Is the phrase "off the lease" a rare idiom or is it just to be interpreted literally?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I've come up against an  interesting phrase in "Talking Ground" by Gavin Casey *(Gavin Stodart Casey (1907-1964), author and journalist. In the 1930’s, Casey began to publish stories about the hard life of the miners in the goldfields of Western Australia. He is the author of the collections "It’s Harder for Girls" (1942) and "Birds of a Feather" (1943), the story “Down an Inclined Plane” (1945), and the novel City of Men (1950). In 1938 he was foundation secretary (president l941-42) of the West Australian branch of the Fellowship of Australian Writers).*

"They had worked together for a year and been cobbers ***off the lease*** before Bill made the discovery that was to change the character of their relationship". *(they had worked in a mine in Australia).*

I have truely looked the Internet over in search of this phrase but had no success. I've also grubbed around all available paper reference books for it. Nevertheless there have been being no traces of "off the lease" brought out ever [by my looking-for].

What actually may "cobbers ***off the lease***" mean here? And why would it seem to be so mega rare?

Answer (score 2):

It is quite common for land used for mining to be leased by the landowner to a mining company until the ore has been extracted.

In Australian English, from [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cobber) first there is

> **cobber**
> a friend

So when they are "cobbers off the lease" I take that to mean they were buddies in their down time, not just work mates, and "off the lease" would mean the same as

> **off site**
> away from the place where people are working or involved in a particular activity

From [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/off-site)